# How to use Google ML Kit as Firebase ml vision is discontinued?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to create a flutter app to detect text from image and I have tried to search resources on internet but all I found was related to `firebase_ml_vision` but it is now discontinued. So I want to use `google_ml_kit` but I couldn't find any code to use it. Can you tell me how to use it in **Flutter?**

Comment: you can find the pub.dev library in this link, feel free to visit here, https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_text_recognition

Answer (score 0):

Multiple components of the ML can be found in this example

[Here](https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/tree/master/example/lib).

Comment: Do you still need this?